# Files sent with ssh2_scp_send() are incomplete on remote server

Tags: php, ssh, file-transfer

I transfer files with PHP and SSH2 to an remote server.

I use this:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');
ssh2_scp_send($connection, '/local/filename', '/remote/filename', 0644);
```

But sometimes the file on the remote server is incomplete. I have the assumption that SSH2 doesn't transfer the EOF or anything else.

Do you have any ideas or solutions?

Comment: Is error reporting enabled? Would you see the message if there were a problem?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is that you don't close the SSH session. So the internal buffers aren't flushed and the files aren't written to disk fully.

Here is a workaround - just close the session with:

```
ssh2_exec($connection, 'exit');
```

This will cause all buffers to be flushed and your files should be transfered completely.

Hope, that helps.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Completely off-topic side note: Your home page has some odd *Umbrüche* in Chrome 14 e.g. `Pr-ogrammiersprachen` and `Nebenb-eruflich`. Not sure why, but I thought you might want to know. @Simon if this answer worked for you, consider marking it accepted using the check mark symbol.

Comment: Thanks Pekka, but I must wait 5 minutes, before I can accept it. :-)

Comment: @Pekka: I used [code.google.com/p/hyphenator](http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator) to automatically add hyphenations. But it really seems a strange hyphenation. Just can't confirm it in Chrome 14. (Checked it and the hyphenations are correct...)

Comment: Umm... guys, you both seem to be from the same place. While it's perfectly okay to answer each others' questions if you're friends, it's not *exactly* how it's supposed to work and do be careful when voting for each other. They have scripts to detect that kind of thing.

Comment: @m--s Sorry, I'm on my laptop where I use Chrome 13, not 14. Definitely looks weird here - maybe because my primary `accept-language` is English?

Comment: @Pekka: May really be, because hyphenator checks the browser language I think.

Comment: @Pekka: Concerning your comment, that Simon Stamm and I are from the same place: semms that is correct, we both have set _Germany_ as our location just as you did...

Comment: @m--s No, I mean that you happen to live [10 km apart from each other](http://maps.google.de/maps?q=Beekstr.+17+Sehnde+to:+Ferdinand-Wahrendorff-Str.+14+Sehnde-Ilten&saddr=Beekstr.+17+Sehnde&daddr=Ferdinand-Wahrendorff-Str.+14+Sehnde-Ilten&hl=en&sll=51.151786,10.415039&sspn=14.985744,43.286133&geocode=FZT1HQMdGkSXAClJTNMNJQiwRzEeeqomleoh8Q%3BFWi8HgMdjJWXACn9WbsP6QiwRzEWiFMyVqKr5A&vpsrc=0&t=h&z=13). And [do work together.](http://musikschule-kalinka.de/) Come *on.*

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4308/discussion-between-m-s-and-pekka)

Comment: @Pekka: I like you. :-) You remind me of me in researching. ;-)

Comment: @Simon well, you will find many fast Googlers on these sites. ;)

Comment: Your solution worked for me! Apparently calling `ssh2_disconnect` was not enough. It would be nice if this were in the official documentation, although it is discussed in the comments: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php

Incidentally the report there is from it happening on Windows; I experienced it on Linux (both boxes) so it is evidently a cross-platform problem.