# Warning during SCP transfer in PHP

Tags: php, scp

I transfer files to a remote server using scp as follows:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');
ssh2_scp_send($connection, '/local/filename', '/remote/filename', 0644);
```

For most servers this works fine. However one remote server had a problem with the transfered file, which has been marked as incomplete.

I found the solution in [Files sent with ssh2_scp_send() are incomplete on remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785094/files-sent-with-ssh2-scp-send-are-incomplete-on-remote-server).

I just had to add

```
ssh2_exec($connection, 'exit');
```

However, after I made this change, some other remote servers seem to not support the exit command. This will result in a php warning:

```
PHP Warning:  ssh2_exec(): Unable to request command execution on remote host in FILE.php on line XX
```

Does anyone know a solution to this problem? I could, obviously, just ignore or supress the warning. However this somehow feels wrong, especialy since the rest of the code is notice free.

Comment: May be this depend on the SSH server.

Comment: Yes, it probably is. The question is, if it is possible to recognize whether the server supports the exit operation or not. If there would be some clue I simply could not invoke the ssh2_exec for the server.

Answer (score 0):

Can you SCP via the CLI to the server giving this error message?:

```
PHP Warning:  ssh2_exec(): Unable to request command execution on remote host in FILE.php on line XX
```

Could be that `ssh2_scp_send()` is doing it's thing via a shell and that `ssh2_exec()` is doing it through a system `exec` call (they're different things) and that your server supports one but not the other. Being able to see logs as [phpseclib's SCP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) provides them would be helpful, but alas, libssh2 does not generate logs..