# php sftp using ssh2 corrupting pdf files

Tags: php, libssh2

I'm trying to transfer a pdf file from our server to another via SFTP. I've checked the files and they are not inherently corrupt. I can scp them on the command line to my computer and they open just fine. **Note**: I can successfully transfer the pdf file, it is just corrupted once it gets to the other server.

I've tried using two methods:

```
conn = ssh2_connect($url, 22);
$auth = ssh2_auth_password($conn, $userName, $password);

$sftp = ssh2_sftp($conn);
file_put_contents("ssh2.sftp://".$sftp.$remoteFilePath, $localFilePath);
```

After looking at this question, I came upon the below question and tried the given answer:

[ssh2_scp_send() using php corrupts pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944374/ssh2-scp-send-using-php-corrupts-pdf)

```
conn = ssh2_connect($url, 22);
$auth = ssh2_auth_password($conn, $userName, $password);

$sftp = ssh2_sftp($conn);
$fp = fopen("ssh2.sftp://".$sftp.$remoteFilePath, "w");
fwrite($fp, $localFilePath);
fclose($fp);
```

This also transfers the file, but is also corrupted so that I cannot open it in my FTP GUI once it is in their server.

I'm now aware of the other php extension that does this. I'll try it out if I can't get this to work but I've put enough time into this, and it SHOULD work. Any thoughts?

Comment: make sure the transfer is binary

Comment: @Dagon I checked and, for example, file_put_contents PHP says in the docs is binary safe. Is there something I have to do to enable binary that I'm not seeing?

Comment: fopen should be r not w? and add b so 'rb' *"If you do not specify the 'b' flag when working with binary files, you may experience strange problems with your data, including broken image files and strange problems with \r\n characters."*

Comment: Really? That produces a whole bunch of errors. My understanding is that I'm opening up a non-existent file for writing (which creates a blank file), and then I write to that newly created file using fwrite(). I tried 'r' and 'rb', which threw a bunch of errors. I also tried 'wb' and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: sorry i got the direction of transfer wrong ;( but the **b** still applies

Answer (score 0):

Look at  http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php

and try:

```
$conn = ssh2_connect($url, 22);
$auth = ssh2_auth_password($conn, $userName, $password);

ssh2_scp_send($conn, $localFilePath, $remoteFilePath, 0644);
```

Comment: This requires the PECL ssh2 extension, in the last line of the question the original asker asked for how to do this without a PHP extension.

Comment: @mjsa ok, not seen, thanks. anyway, it's worth a try

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I had $localFilePath written as so:

```
$localFilePath = "/path/to/my/file.pdf";
```

file_put_contents() and fwrite() were treating the variable as a *string*. So it would create a new pdf file, with its contents being the string filepath. I only discovered this after trying to transfer a small .txt file. SO, adding this fixed the problem:

```
$localFilePath = fopen("/path/to/my/file.pdf", "r");
```

I feel that it's strange that I haven't seen this used in the examples that I've seen that sftp using this approach, but there you go.